# How to reference (foreign key) an inherited column

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, foreign-keys

I have a users table that has uuid, last_updated info and so forth that all the other tables in the database inherit from. However let's say plant_type inherits uuid from this users table and a plant table now references plant_type. Can I still implement foreign key relationship to plant type on the column that is inherited?
Current error message: ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "plant_type".
NB plant_type inherits uuid from users table (so it's an extended column)

```
CREATE TABLE user_update(
    uuid TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    last_update TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    last_update_by TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE plant_type(
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    common_name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    scientific_name TEXT UNIQUE,
    notes TEXT, 
) INHERITS (user_update);



CREATE TABLE plant(
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    geom GEOMETRY(POINT, 4326) NOT NULL, 
    plant_type_uuid TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES plant_type(uuid)
) INHERITS (user_update);
```

Expectation: plant type uuid is a foreign key in plant due to the one-to-many relationship

Answer (score 0):

Constraints are not inherited. Your example will work fine if you create a unique constraint on `plant_type.uuid`.

To quote [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS):

> A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply to single tables, not to their inheritance children.